# C++ Code not compiling of RPi after upgrading from Wheezy to Buster

Tags: gpio, i2c, raspbian-buster

I am getting the error: ‘i2c_smbus_write_byte_data’ was not declared in this scope when trying to compile GPIO code. I have a clean install of Buster (I had accidentally corrupted Wheezy).

On Wheezy, the i2c_smbus_write_byte_data method was a header method defined in /usr/include/linux/i2c-dev.h. On Buster the smbus_read and smbus_write methods are no longer defined in this file. Following the standard Google logic:

1.i2c-tools and libi2c-dev are installed and up to date via apt-get
2.extern "C" { } around the linux/i2c-dev.h hasn't helped
3.sudo find / -name "i2c-dev.h" confirms the only i2c-dev.h on the system is linux/i2c-dev.h

Is there a new approach to i2c on Buster now or am I missing an install of another i2c-dev.h file?

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: I included a copy of i2c-dev.h from Wheezy local to the build and it compiled and runs as expected. Though for curiosity and best practice I would love to know whether we should be using a different approach to i2c now or whether this indicates that I'm still missing a dependancy in the system.

Comment: How do you know that the kernel support for i2c is the same between Wheezy and Buster? Why not install the correct library for Buster with `sudo apt install libi2c-dev`?

Comment: There's a dummy i2c-dev.h and a usuable i2c-dev.h which should install with the `-dev` package Dougie mentions.  The existence of the dummy can make this pretty confusing.

Comment: The Foundation has never recommended, or supported ANY upgrade, let alone from Wheezy to Buster!

Comment: Thanks Dougie and goldilocks - I did install libi2c-dev with apt and it does show latest version installed and up to date. It didn't install a second i2c-dev.h file.

Comment: Thanks Milliways, I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I had code running on Wheezy, and I installed Buster and now the code doesn't run due to unmet dependency. That being said is apt-get upgrade distro not recommended?